# Share a folder with USB (as an external Hard Drive)

Tags: usb, external-hdd, sharing

I have an old laptop with Ubuntu. I store all my movies and videos on it. I want to plug this laptop into my LG Smart TV with a USB cable and I want my TV to see this folder only as a USB drive. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

- It may be difficult to make your old laptop into a USB hard disk drive for the TV.
- It might be easier to plug the external video output (VGA, DVI, HDMI, ...) to the TV's video input (often VGA and HDMI). You may need a converting cable, if the ports on the computer and TV do not match.
- It would be straightforward to get a USB drive, HDD or SSD, or an external box for a SATA drive and a standard SATA HDD or SSD and copy your multimedia files into that. Then you can connect the USB drive to either the laptop or the TV.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Many laptops do not support this because the USB controllers in them are not capable of acting as anything but a USB host. However, with USB 3.0 and On The Go (OTG) this becomes a bit more plausible as one of the devices may be capable.

This was also discussed on [Unix Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195765/is-usb-to-usb-data-transfer-between-two-linux-oses-possible) over the years you may find some of that helpful.

This was also discussed on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/427092/how-to-turn-a-folder-into-usb-drive-mass-storage) with similar responses.

Regarding how you would do it if it's actually supported would be to follow the steps in this [USB_Gadget/Mass_Storage](http://linux-sunxi.org/USB_Gadget/Mass_storage) wiki article. However, it would require compiling your own kernel module.

Here is also some info on compiling your kernel with [USB Gadget Support](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/113944/exposing-nfs-mount-via-usb)